# make the player start on sameoffset on a 2d game regardless of the screenresolution on unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make the player start on sameoffset on a 2d game regardless of the screenresolution.This is for a sidescrolling platformer.I want to make the player keeps the same offset from the left on all resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by treating the screen as a range of 0 to 1f both vertically and horizontally. This way you can specify offsets regardless of screen resolution. So for example if you want to have the player at an offset of 1/3rd screen size horizontally, you can easily calculate the resolution dependent offset by:

```
float offsetLeft = Screen.width * 0.33f; // 33% from left border
```

Now you got a pixel offset that you can use to position the player. It will always be 33% from the left border of the screen no matter what resolution is used.

So for example if screen resolution is  1920x1200 then offsetLeft would be 634px in that case while it would calculate to 422px when having a resolution of 1280x1024.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try this. But how can I set the screen as a range of 0 to 1f???

Comment: You only do this in your calculation. All your game logic would work with offsets specified within the range of 0..1. Then you can use a simple set of functions to calculate actual pixels (depending on the actual resolution).

Comment: using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScreenSetup : MonoBehaviour {
 float offsetLeft ;
 float offsetRight ;
 Vector3 pos;
 Transform player;
 void Awake(){
  GameObject player_go=GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
  player = player_go.transform;


  offsetLeft = Screen.width * .0059f;
  offsetRight= Screen.height*  .01f;
  pos = player.transform.position;
  pos.x = offsetLeft;
  pos.y = offsetRight;
  player.transform.position = pos;
 }

Comment: still not working... the code I tried is posted above if needed.on some resolutions am getting the player on screen. But not all. I think the solution is to place the player inside the viewport of the camera. I didnt try the calculation for different pixels as because I have no idea on how to do that. Any help is highly apprecieated. thanks.